# Destructuring a Sequelize query

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I'm having trouble deconstructing a simple Sequelize query.

```
const character = await Character.findAll({
  order: ['created_at'],
  attributes: ['id', 'name', 'created_at'],
});
```

I want to access the "created_at" of the list, but I try to

```
const { created_at } = character;
```

But it returns undefined.

I need to subtract the current date from the created_at date.

Could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong or how could I do it?
I have Moment.js installed if needed.

Query return

```
{ "id": 10, "name": "John Doe", "created_at": "2020-08-08T20:52:06.262Z" }, 
{ "id": 11, "name": "Mary Jane", "created_at": "2020-08-08T21:01:49.562Z" }, 
{ "id": 12, "name": "Clark Kent", "created_at": "2020-08-08T21:02:51.948Z" } 
]
```

Comment: [
  {
    "id": 10,
    "name": "John Doe",
    "created_at": "2020-08-08T20:52:06.262Z"
  },
  {
    "id": 11,
    "name": "Mary Jane",
    "created_at": "2020-08-08T21:01:49.562Z"
  },
  {
    "id": 12,
    "name": "Clark Kent",
    "created_at": "2020-08-08T21:02:51.948Z"
  }
}

Answer (score 0):

In you case you are trying to do a destructuring from an array. But it only works in an object.

To it to work you should use an index.

Something like:

```
const { created_at } = character[0];
```

Notice that it will only destruct the position `zero` from your results contained in the character array. If you do not would like the position zero you should use another function to choose the desired result.